# Aurelia + Php Possible/Recommended?

Tags: php, aurelia

Before this question gets closed, I know the setup above is possible. I just want clarification on some things.

I just started learning Aurelia because I want to convert one of my projects into a web app. My project is built with html+css+JavaScript(jQuery)+ PHP(MySql).

I havent used any sort of framework before.

In the guide, they mention a few ways to setup a web server. I used the http server with node. Now this is where I need some help understanding a few things.

I dont want to use node.js. I want to use PHP on the server. Will that work and how?

When using Apache server, I know any PHP page is sent to the interpreter that renders the final html. I use XAMPP and its apache comes bundled with PHP. Does the http server used by node come with PHP? Is this even a sensible question?

Now I know Aurelia is purely front end. If it used to make single page applications, it uses Ajax. So now I made the following assumption:

Using Aurelia, the user accesses the root page of the app that the web server sends. After that, Aurelia makes various Ajax requests to the server which will use my PHP files to do database query stuff.

Is that right or am I missing something. And can I just use xampp(apache) to host my app instead of server from node?

Comment: You're correct in everything you wrote and you can use xampp to serve `.js` and other pages that are requested using AJAX.

Comment: Have you used Aurelia in conjunction with PHP before?

Comment: I haven't used Aurelia at all, but I don't see where PHP comes into place here. Aurelia uses HTTP to transfer data back and forth, it's irrelevant if it's PHP that provides the data, or Ruby, or Java, or `node.js`.. it's important that the web server is returning correctly formatted output. What you use behind it is completely irrelevant, which is great, since you can use whatever you like.

Comment: If you are open minded and like to simplify app deployments that is independent of any lang/platform give docker a try. With simple config files you can configure a host to run a web server or any service you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia is a framework that, after you export it to any server, does not rely on any back-end software at all. This means that with the help of the `http- / fetch-client` API, you can just call out to your php script.

I have an example in my github:
https://github.com/rjpvroegop/randyvroegop.nl-made-with-aurelia

Here I use the http-client to post data to my php script wich has a very simple email functionality.

You can see the action inside my `view-model` in `src/pages/contact/index.js`.
You can see the PHP script in `src/assets/components/contactengine.php`.

These work the way they should. Note: you have to change your gulp build if you want your `PHP` served the way I serve mine, from the dist folder after `gulp-watch` or `gulp-export`.

Next to that you can use any back-end functionality you would like, as long as it returns the proper data. This PHP script does that. If you would download my distribution to test this you can simply do the following:

`gulp export` from your terminal in the root folder

copy everything from the export folder to your PHP webserver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've looked through your project and understand what's happening but what did u mean by "if you want your PHP to be served like mine"?. I am new to gulp and just started learning it today.

Comment: Aurelia Does not have Gulp support for anything but project files so if you want to serve php or json from the SRC folder you have to adjust the build scripts and paths in the build folder. You can add them manually after the export too, but that requires attention and your team might not cooperate or understand that. If your php is not integrated inside your SRC folder, it's no problem so don't worry about it.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks for the very helpful info.

Comment: Btw, is there a reason u don't bundle ur pages in app-build.js? Also, in source folder, your images and components are in an assets folder. After build, assets folder is gone. Why does that happen?

Comment: TL;DR: Lack of knowledge. => To be honest I created this website in Aurelia in about one or two days. I don't think I fully understood how that worked at the time. I've come to further understand Aurelia and the Gulp setup the last few weeks and bundle everything except for images in my current project. I would say it's best to bundle everything as much as possible for performance. Try and find out what works best for your project.

Comment: Ok. Btw, sorry for going off topic but I was primarily interested in PHP to implement authentication in my web app. Just standard PHP sessions. Will that work? I saw some info somewhere about methods that can be called before views can be loaded. Can I use one of those to check if there is an active session(PHP) and redirect to desired view if its present? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of Aurelia, you probably want to check out something like OAuth2 and keep track of your sessions in JS, but Aurelia does not provide technology out of the box for as far as I know.